# Could not echo /map topic using Nav2_map_server

Tags: rviz, map-server, nav2, ros-foxy, ros2-launch

I am using ROS2-foxy with ubuntu 20.04 LTS and wanted to load a map using the map_server from Nav2_map server. i found this old thread from ROS answers regarding this (https://answers.ros.org/question/398095/ros2-nav2-map_server-problems-loading-map-with-nav2_map_server/)
and as per the instructions i created a launch file :

```py
import os
import yaml
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch.actions import ExecuteProcess
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
import launch_ros.actions


def generate_launch_description():

    ld = LaunchDescription()

    # map file
    map_file_path = os.path.join(
        get_package_share_directory('map_loader'),
        'maps',
        'map.yaml'
    )

    map_server_cmd = Node(
        package='nav2_map_server',
        executable='map_server',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[{'yaml_filename': map_file_path}])


    lifecycle_nodes = ['map_server']
    use_sim_time = True
    autostart = True

    start_lifecycle_manager_cmd = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='nav2_lifecycle_manager',
        executable='lifecycle_manager',
        name='lifecycle_manager',
        output='screen',
        emulate_tty=True, 
        parameters=[{'use_sim_time': use_sim_time},
                    {'autostart': autostart},
                    {'node_names': lifecycle_nodes}])


    ld.add_action(map_server_cmd)
    ld.add_action(start_lifecycle_manager_cmd)

    return ld
```

when i launch this code it is partially working the necessary topics are created
and the nodes are running 
`ros2 node list   /lifecycle_manager /lifecycle_manager_service_client /map_server`

`ros2 topic list /clock /map /map_server/transition_event /parameter_events /rosout`

And the console Output of launch file is :

```
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/csl-n/.ros/log/2023-11-25-15-50-13-210683-csln-19412
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [lifecycle_manager-2]: process started with pid [19416]
[INFO] [map_server-1]: process started with pid [19414]
[lifecycle_manager-2] [INFO] [1700907613.604006808] [lifecycle_manager]: Creating
[map_server-1] [INFO] [1700907613.604777244] [map_server]: 
[map_server-1]  map_server lifecycle node launched. 
[map_server-1]  Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[map_server-1]  See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[map_server-1] [INFO] [1700907613.604984016] [map_server]: Creating
[lifecycle_manager-2] [INFO] [1700907613.611170206] [lifecycle_manager]: Creating and initializing lifecycle service clients
[lifecycle_manager-2] [INFO] [1700907613.612512906] [lifecycle_manager]: Starting managed nodes bringup...
[lifecycle_manager-2] [INFO] [1700907613.612578969] [lifecycle_manager]: Configuring map_server
[map_server-1] [INFO] [1700907613.613065551] [map_server]: Configuring
[map_server-1] [INFO] [map_io]: Loading yaml file: /home/csl-n/colcon_ws/install/map_loader/share/map_loader/maps/map.yaml
[map_server-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: resolution: 0.05
[map_server-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: origin[0]: -10
[map_server-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: origin[1]: -10
[map_server-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: origin[2]: 0
[map_server-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: free_thresh: 0.196
[map_server-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: occupied_thresh: 0.65
[map_server-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: mode: trinary
[map_server-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: negate: 0
[map_server-1] [INFO] [map_io]: Loading image_file: /home/csl-n/colcon_ws/install/map_loader/share/map_loader/maps/map.pgm
[map_server-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: Read map /home/csl-n/colcon_ws/install/map_loader/share/map_loader/maps/map.pgm: 384 X 384 map @ 0.05 m/cell
[lifecycle_manager-2] [INFO] [1700907613.653008697] [lifecycle_manager]: Activating map_server
[map_server-1] [INFO] [1700907613.653411145] [map_server]: Activating
[lifecycle_manager-2] [INFO] [1700907613.655107777] [lifecycle_manager]: Managed nodes are active
```

From the console output i can see that the map_server can access and read both map.yaml and the map.pgm file.
But when i echo the /map topic it prints out nothing.
I also observed that the person who originally posted the code had these lines extra in their terminal output:

```
[map_server-1] [INFO] [1689846435.454019105] [map_server]: Creating bond (map_server) to lifecycle manager.
[lifecycle_manager-2] [INFO] [1689846435.557139113] [lifecycle_manager]: Server map_server connected with bond.
[lifecycle_manager-2] [INFO] [1689846435.557207313] [lifecycle_manager]: Managed nodes are active
[lifecycle_manager-2] [INFO] [1689846435.557242914] [lifecycle_manager]: Creating bond timer...
```

Creating bond and creating bond timer , i am not sure what they are(probably to control the map_server node by using the lifecycle_manager).

1. How do i echo and access the /map topic data?
2. Also after echoing that how can i load that map into Rviz?
   Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know if this helps you, but understand the mapserver publishes the map data a single time. You need to echo that topic and then run the mapserver to see it publish. Or, rerun the mapserver once you have started the echo.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably just using the wrong QoS :-) The map server publishes on transient-local QoS which isn't compatible with the default QoS settings if using `ros2 topic echo`. You should set the transient local setting on the CLI echoing and you should see it fine. That's probably the same issue you have with rviz2. If the server thinks its OK, its probably doing its thing OK.

Comment: So, i tried using this command `ros2 topic echo /map --qos-durability transient_local`. But still got nothing.